# Do we have dropdown widget in maximo anywhere

Tags: maximo-anywhere

We have a requirement to display drop down with values inside maximo anywhere app. Does maximo anywhere has such a widget? I could see view , button, dialog widgets in maximo anywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the components provided by the platform are listed in app.xsd resource.

Maybe the element called combobox may fit for your need. To check its required and optional attributes use also the app.xsd file.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Could you please share the app.xsd file location

Comment: I tried combo box like below but not working. Pls help                          <combobox id="combo.loc1" placeHolder="Select from List" value="['1','2']" layoutInsertAt="edtloc" label="Place"></combobox>

Comment: <combobox id="header_combobox_list" value="{0}" required="true" layoutInsertAt="comboloc" resolverClass="application.handlers.testHandler" resolverFunction="getList">
 <domainValues id="header_combobox_location_listdata" >
  <domainValue displayValue="test" keyValue="1"   id="val"/>
  <domainValue displayValue="test1" keyValue="2"   id="val1"/>
 </domainValues>
</combobox>

Comment: I also tried below code                                                                       <combobox id="ts" label="test" placeHolder="test" value="test" labelCss="crewheader">
                                  <domainValues id="tst">
                                         <domainValue id="ajsA" keyValue="tstt" displayValue="test" defaultValue="true" />
                                         <domainValue id="ajsAcx" keyValue="tsttr" displayValue="test1" />
                                  </domainValues>
                           </combobox>